# Is this Bootstrap CSS Google Adsense Responsive behaviour correct?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, adsense

I'm having a very difficult time to make my Google AdSense horizontal ad become responsive on a desktop resolution when resized.

When the Advertisement loads on a mobile - it loads correctly, i.e. nice and small.

But on a desktop it does initially load correct but then if you resize the brower it makes the page very ugly because you can scroll all the way along the Advertisement which pushes the site sideways....

Here's the code:

```
<style>
.example_responsive_1 { width: 320px; height: 100px; }
@media(min-width: 500px) { .example_responsive_1 { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
@media(min-width: 800px) { .example_responsive_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
</style>
```

And the actual HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

          <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
          <!-- IC Throughtout Site -->
          <ins class="adsbygoogle example_responsive_1"
               style="display:block"
               data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXX"
               data-ad-slot="XXX"
               data-ad-format="horizontal"></ins>
          <script>
          (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
          </script>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for all help.

Comment: did you ever tried to use max-width on your media queries?

Comment: I didn't - sorry i'm not too sure how to do that - I took the code from the recommended Google AdSense page...can you share how you'd approach the problem?

Comment: You can try adding `body { overflow-x: hidden; }` to your css, but i don't if that violates the ToS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap, you can simply add class like below to make ads better alignment.

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle ml-4 mr-4">
```